# How to add a moving average line to a line chart with a legend in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, linechart, moving-average

I am a newbie to PowerBI and I cannot seem to add a moving average line to my visual. I will first provide a test table and a screenshot of my test report. (Actual data is more in-depth and has way more data).

[Test Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj3w2.png)

[Test Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hmRM.png)

So in this visual I need a moving average line for each item that is currently displayed. (I know there is not much date data for a moving average but my actual data has enough). I know my equation for moving average in my real report is correct however the issue I am facing is that I can not add it to the visual. I tried adding it to the y-axis but it is not allowed. I believe this is because of how my visual is setup.

[Test Visual Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbkQs.png)

I have tried adding the moving average measure to the y-axis, x-axis, and legend value but it is not allowed. I have also tried scatter chart but that also does not work.

Comment: What about adding it to your Secondary y-axis?